# How to copy to clipboard a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER value in SQL Azure Manager?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to get a value from a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER column from a table in the SQL Azure manager (silverlight).

Right click on the data only get me to the Silverlight "About" page, double click do nothing.

It works on a varchar column (the manager allow to select text from the value, and the COPY), but not on a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER column.

I tried to use the following query :

```
select convert(nvarchar(50), guidColumn) from table
```

But, it doesn't allow to select the data either.

Thanks